# Module over nonassociative algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have $A$ an algebra $*$ that is commutative an have an identity
$(a^2b)b=((ab)ba$ and asking me verify conditions conditions for a  $A$-module $*$ $M$.

How I would use Linearization of identity?

$*$ is the property name?

Comment: This looks similar to a Jordan algebra. We can define modules for all nonassociative algebras, see Schafer's book on "Nonassociative algebras".